# MySQL query sets field to 0 instead of blank string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

This one's puzzling me. I have a MySQL query, being run though PDO:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "UPDATE member SET acode='' AND status='active' WHERE username=:u" );
$stmt->bindValue( ':u', $member->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->execute();
```

The `acode` field gets set to 0 for some reason. It was created with

```
`acode` varchar(8) NOT NULL
```

Is there something special I need to do when using prepared statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gidday,

The problem comes with this part of your query:

```
SET acode='' AND status='active'
```

the AND turns this into the boolean check of '' AND status='active', which evaluates to 0. Change your query to:

```
SET acode='', status='active'
```

Comment: Heh, it happens - much like my all-too-common habit of doing an `UPDATE` on a Parameters table and forgetting the `WHERE` clause!